# Adding max(count) and min(count) to query

Tags: sql, oracle11g, max, min

I am trying to add max and min to the query below:

```
SELECT category, COUNT(distinct VIN) COUNT
FROM stock
group by category
order by category ASC
```

The desired results are to show the category with the most items in the count and to show the category with the least items in the count.

CURRENT OUTPUT:

```
CATEGORY COUNT
Sedan    25
SUV      15
TRUCK    15
AWD      10
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
CATEGORY COUNT
Sedan    25
AWD      10
```

I basically want to show the maximum count which in this example would be SEDAN and the minimum category count which would be AWD

I believe this would require a `HAVING` statement with a nested sub-query, any help would be much appreicated

I am using Oracle 11g

Comment: "*display the maximum count and minimum count per category*" - doesn't make sense. There is only one count per category. Can you **edit** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you for your reply I have changed the question and provided the desired ouput :D

Comment: Easy to use Union!!!

Comment: @N.Molderf thank you for your reply union.. i am not too familiar with this function would you have a link that might help me :)

Comment: @ITworldR something like this Select Max from table UNION Select MIn from table or add SQLFiddle i will create this query

Comment: [Union](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: @N.Molderf would this select the max category count and the minimum category count? so the union operator would go after my query, correct?

Comment: @ITworldR look at the answer you have correct answer without union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(VIN), Category 
from STOCK
having count(VIN)=(select max(count(VIN)) from STOCK group by Category )
OR count(VIN)=(select min(count(VIN))  from STOCK group by Category )
group by Category;
```

Comment: this query was perfect :D

Answer (score 1):

The best way I can think of doing this is to union two queries to find the max and min counts like below:

```
Select category, CNT
FROM
(SELECT category, COUNT(distinct VIN) CNT
FROM stock
group by category
Order by CNT asc) a
where RowNum = 1
UNION
Select category, CNT
FROM
(SELECT category, COUNT(distinct VIN) CNT
FROM stock
group by category
Order by CNT desc) a
where RowNum = 1
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/555515/18/0

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   count(VIN), 
   Category 
from STOCK
having count(VIN)=
    (
        select max(count(VIN))  
        from STOCK group by project_status_id 
    )
    OR count(project_status_id)=
    (
        select min(count(project_status_id))  
        from project_status group by project_status_id 
     )
group by project_status_id
```

Comment: yes you are correct! this is the answer what i mean

Comment: Welcome. keep it up. :)

Comment: I don't understand where project_status_id and table project_status came from? Copy / Paste error?

Comment: yess christian it was copy paste error. you can refer my next comment.

Comment: select count(VIN), Category 
from STOCK
having count(VIN)=(select max(count(VIN)) from STOCK group by Category )
OR count(VIN)=(select min(count(VIN))  from STOCK group by Category )
group by Category;

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61d38/6)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE counts ( CATEGORY, "COUNT" ) AS
          SELECT 'Sedan',    25 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'SUV',      15 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'TRUCK',    15 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'AWD',      10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MAX( CATEGORY ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY "COUNT" ASC ) AS CATEGORY,
       MAX( "COUNT" ) AS "COUNT"
FROM   COUNTS
UNION ALL
SELECT MIN( CATEGORY ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY "COUNT" ASC ) AS CATEGORY,
       MIN( "COUNT" ) AS "COUNT"
FROM   COUNTS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/61d38/6/0)**:

```
| CATEGORY | COUNT |
|----------|-------|
|    Sedan |    25 |
|      AWD |    10 |
```